# Issue with Lotus Notes 8.0 : It doesn't relaunch after closing

Tags: lotus-notes

I'm using Lotus Notes on Windows 7, and the problem is that the Lotus Notes doesn't relaunch after my closing it. I have to log-off or reboot in order to start it again. I see this symptom a couple of weeks ago.

What might be the solution? I found the 'Notes Kill', but it's erased.

Comment: The process might still be running in the task manager.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have that problem in our company too. The issue is that there is still one Notes related task running the background. You have to kill it through the process explorer - it's called something with `*notes*` or `*nl*` - I am not sure.

Try that - works every time for me!